# My nested slider isn't displaying the images

Tags: jquery, slider, nested, orbit

I'm having an issue displaying a slider inside of my main slider. I have everything linked up correctly and everything seems to be functioning correctly except for the fact that the images won't display. I'm pretty sure it's not a z-index issue because I have already checked that using Firebug.

link: http://toughguppyproductions.com/2013

The slide that I'm referring to is the 4th circle with the computer icon called "graphic design". When you click on that you'll see the slide I'm referring to. On the right of the slide you'll see the two arrows for the slider as well as the dots displaying how many images are in the slider.

Please help, I've been racking my brain for about a week trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The div in which you placed the images is 1x1 pixels. So you are currently displaying the upper left pixel of your gallery (look at the Inline css on the div with id='featured'). :)

As i promised. open orbit_home.js and replace

```
{"z-index" : 1}
```

and

```
{"z-index" : 2}
```

to

```
{"z-index" : 1, "display" : "none"}
```

and

```
"z-index" : 3
```

to

```
"z-index" : 3, "display":"block"
```

in all occurrences of the .css command

Last edit: Add the following line to the end of your css file:

```
line 88 and 91 from the  orbit_home.js :
```

`"display":"block"` to `"display":"none"`

as in:

```
 function unlock() {
                locked = false;
            }
            function lock() { 
                locked = true;
            }

            //If there is only a single slide remove nav, timer and bullets
            if(slides.length == 1) {
                options.directionalNav = false;
                options.timer = false;
                options.bullets = false;
            }

            //Set initial front photo z-index and fades it in
            slides.eq(activeSlide)
                .css({"z-index" : 3, "display":"block"})
                .fadeIn(function() {
                    //brings in all other slides IF css declares a display: none
                    slides.css({"display":"block"})
                });

// ==============
// ! TIMER   
// ==============
```

becoming:

function unlock() {
                locked = false;
            }
            function lock() { 
                locked = true;
            }

```
        //If there is only a single slide remove nav, timer and bullets
        if(slides.length == 1) {
            options.directionalNav = false;
            options.timer = false;
            options.bullets = false;
        }

        //Set initial front photo z-index and fades it in
        slides.eq(activeSlide)
            .css({"z-index" : 3, "display":"block"})
            .fadeIn(function() {
                //brings in all other slides IF css declares a display: none
                slides.css({"display":"none"})
            });

// ==============
// ! TIMER   
// ==============
```

Comment: I changed this to the correct width and height thinking that it would fix it and all it did was displayed all of the images together stacked on top of each other.

Comment: well if they have transparent background(as they are) they will stack on top of each other (that's what z-index is for). 
Try setting "display:none;" on the images you don't want to show and then make the JS alter it to display just the selected image.

Comment: Alright, I'm kind of a novice when it comes to javascript, but outside of the main slide that it's nested in it works fine. I was just wondering if there was some reason due to the nesting that was making it function incorrectly.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick fix, you can just add background to all images (background-color: white;) which is not advisable. Otherwise I suggest you read (this)[http://api.jquery.com/show/] and try to edit your script. 

My suggestion is to look at the orbit_home.js and check all the places where it changes the z-index of css and add the display: none/ display: block; I'll edit my post to give instructions

Comment: Thanks for all the help Hristo. I just added the new css properties as you advised but it's still not quite right. Maybe you can check it out and see how it's displaying? I also changed the div in the js file to the exact dimensions as the pngs being displayed.

Comment: I also noticed that the transition effect is not working when I cycle through the images. It's set to be a "horizontal-push" and it didn't work before or after the js change.

Comment: Sry for the late response I went home after work. So the problem is that you have left a few places where you should have placed "z-index" : 3, "display":"block" namely between lines 341 and 388. Also you should make them hidden (display:none) from the very beginning using css. :)

Comment: Alright, so I kind of got it to work with your help so far. I added the display block to the rest but upon first load it still displays all of the images at once until you cycle through at least 1 time. It's also not allowing me to use the transition effects. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, so the images cycle through correctly from the beginning, but the start of the slider is blank until you click an arrow and the transitions still don't work.

Comment: Sooo changing the content of lines 88 and 91 didn't help?

Comment: It did help, but I don't get a first initial image. I have to click at least once for an image to display and then it's alright. Is there a way to make it display an image right off the bat?

Comment: Then can you not revert it for me to see something? (Because currently it's set to "display":"block")

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Did you clear cache? It's set to display: none for me. That's what you would like it set at right?

Comment: sry my bad XD. hmm have you tried line 88 with dispay: block and 91 with display: none?

Comment: You rly need 20 rep so that we can move all this conversation to a chat room. XD 

Pls substitute line 88 with this:  
            .css({"z-index" : 3, "display":"block"}) 

and let me see what happens (i am currently spaming f5 to to verify that the cache is not messing with me again.)

Comment: hmmm. Same as before. It functions but I'm still not getting the first image to display. How can I improve my rep, any suggestions? I also ran into this this morning and tried it out but it didn't function very well: [link](https://github.com/zurb/orbit/issues/9)

Comment: On my PC it works right now... XD
As for rep, you have to help ppl or ask questions which contribute to society.

Comment: I see. I'm on a Mac and it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly in Safari or Firefox. It's all mashed together actually in Safari. Maybe I need to abandon this slider altogether. Do you know of a good slider that displays pngs by any chance?

Comment: I just plugged in the new js mods that I pulled from that link for you to take a look at. It doesn't function the way it should but it's pretty close. Would you mind checking it out? It might be something stupid that I'm overlooking.

Comment: I have a new proposal for you. Line 91, where it says "display":"none", change it with "left":"-400px" ... i think this should finally fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

theres an inline css `height: 1px;width: 1px;` in your #featured div. :)